# How to find out what auto-starts my php?

Tags: php, homebrew

So I installed `php56` using homebrew a couple of months ago. I configured my OSX Yosemite somehow so that it auto-starts php when I login. But now I don't know how I did it anymore! Both `/Users/{USERNAME}/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/Library/LaunchDaemons`don't contain anything relevant. In the latter, there is `homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`, but that doesn't really have anything to do with it. That's the only homebrew plist I could find.
Also, when I run `brew services list`, I get

```
bash-3.2$ brew services list
Name    Status  User Plist
dnsmasq started root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
php56   stopped
```

It says php isn't even running! Yet `phpinfo()`works and shows `Version 5.6.23`. I turned of cache in chrome, too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How do you call phpinfo()?

In CLI? Than you´re starting php yourself.

In a web browser on localhost? Look for a web server running on your machine.

(I don´t know a thing about web servers on an Apple machine, but it is interesting that there is no php running at all. php 5.6 should have the php-fpm service running; but, as it is not, I guess the web server accesses php via cgi.)

Comment: Yes, it's on localhost. How do I look for a web server on my machine? I honestly don't know...

Comment: Wherever you did look for "is php running?" (the process list?). Apache is the most widely used web server, so you might want to look for that. Anything with "http" in the name is probably a web server. If none of these can be found, try [this list](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/web-servers-list).